# How to save all versions of a project build with git in different repositories

Tags: repository, git-commit, git

I'm a beginner in git, I have learned the basics of git and started working on my web project with git.
Now after a month working on it, I have created more than 10 versions and with each version, I have had a git commit.

**And now wanted to save all my versions in different repositories -like every folder containing my project progress till the subsequent commit.**

I've googled it but not got any relevant/working solution.
So if anyone has the answer on how to do or is there any script with which I could get all my versions in different repository.. **pls help!**

Comment: You can check out older versions if you want to access them without creating a new repository.  If you really need a folder with each version, does it need to be a repository, or do you just need the files?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), what is it you're specifically trying to achieve?